# DIV has multiple classes assigned, but I want to apply a style to only one of those classes, is it possible?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I envision doing:

```
<div class="a1 a2" style="width:15%">
My Text
</div>
```

Now .a2 is a colorized bar that will overlay My Text, with a variable width (which is why I need to declare its width in the HTML).  In this example, I need ONLY a2 to be 15% width.   But I still need .a1 to remain 100% width (which is declared in CSS).

Is this at all possible or am I going about this the wrong way

Comment: Unfortunately, you're so off that the question makes no sense at all. You should read about: HTML, HTML Styles & CSS

Comment: Do you want the `<div>` to be 15% width or 100% width?

Comment: That is not a good idea. both classes, having same rule-set.

Comment: What you have there are two classes on the same element. Styles don't apply to classes - they apply to elements. Since you have only one element, either the style is going to apply *or* it isn't. And particularly since this is an inline style, it doesn't matter what classes the element has (`!important` notwithstanding).

Comment: Before you go saying that something is not possible, can you tell why they should be the same single element, and why can there not be two different `div`s. Based on your explanation, it sounds like you want to have two different "physical" things.

Comment: @roope If there were two different elements then it is a fundamentally different question then the one asked which is trying to do this with one element

Comment: Is it more important to achieve a result or to achieve that result with a very particular way? Most of the time, the result itself is more important, and people here recommend best practices of achieving those results instead of forcing some way of doing the same. That is why I'm asking if there is a reason why you just cannot have two divs? Because I don't see one at the moment. Anyway, a single element can have multiple backgrounds, if that helps. Maybe you can have one background that is positioned so that it fills 15% and the other 100%. Hard to say because your desired result is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just for posterity sake, it seems this is not possible, so the answer to the question is NO.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two different div containers:

```
<div class="a1">
    <div class="a2">
         Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply the style to each respective class.